# send latitude, longitude to mysql by JDBC every 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, jdbc, gps, latitude-longitude

currently I want to send my GPS latitude and longitude to MYSQL by use of JDBC.
To retrieve GPS lat, long I've used the code below and I have GPS tracker code in GPSTracker class. This would toast Latitude and Longitude by any time pressing the button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnShowLocation;
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //testDB();

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //    txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);

            //   btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
            // txtv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                //     txtv = getText().getApplicationContext(this);
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To send JDBC data to MYSQL, I've used the code below which can only send the values that I giving to it in parenthesis:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
    GPSTracker gps;
    double tmplat = 0;
    double tmplong = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appDB();
    }

    public void appDB() {
        //   TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtv);
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                //connection to data base.
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.6:3306/k_sql1", USER, PASS);

                //create a statement
             //   String result = "Database connection successfull !\n";
                Statement statement = con.createStatement();

                // execute sql query
                String sql = ("INSERT INTO `gps-data2`(`ID`,`Latitude`,`Longitude`) VALUES (1,123.45678, 345.678901);");

                // String sql = (" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GPS_data ( ID int, Latitude Double, Longitude Double ); INSERT INTO GPS_data (`ID`,`Latitude`,`Longitude`) VALUES (1,1234.5678,56789.123456); ");

                statement.executeUpdate(sql);

              //  System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Please tell me how to combine these 2 systems and send GPS data (lat, lng) to mysql by use of JDBC method. I know it maybe better to use PHP but for this project I want it by use of JDBC. Appreciate if can give me a simple applicable solution.

Comment: This is the answer what I was looking for to retrieve GPS parameters programmatically and send it to database directly by use of onClickListener.

Comment: Please describe the topology.  I envision a mobile device gathering GPS coordinates, then sending them to a stationary server which will insert into a database.  Is this correct, or not?

Comment: If your intention is to store GPS coordinates in a database like mysql then u can use this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer what I was looking for to retrieve GPS parameters programmatically and send it to database directly by use of onClickListener.
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
    String sql = null;
    GPSTracker gps;
    double tmplat = 0;
    double tmplong = 0;
    Button btnShowLocation;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    TextView tv;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);
     btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                appDB();
            } else {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
        });
}
protected void appDB() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/k_sql1", USER, PASS);

        String result = "Database connection successfull !\n";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        String sql = ("INSERT INTO `gps-data2`(`Latitude`,`Longitude`) VALUES (" + latitude + ", " + longitude + ");");

        statement.executeUpdate(sql);


    } catch (SQLException se) {

        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
           f